# AWS ECS Fargate - Service Connect not updating /etc/hosts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-service-connect, ecs-service-connect

I have two services running on ECS: service_1 and service_2. Service_2 uses service_1. Both services are on the same namespace.

Service Connect service configuration on service_1 sets DNSName and port in the client alias section. Let's say DNSName is set to `service1`.

Deployment is done using Terraform.

When deploying both services in parallel, `/etc/hosts` on service_1 container will have entry similar to `127.255.0.1 service1`, and so it can discover itself. However on service_2, there is no such entry in `/etc/hosts` created, so it is not able to find service_1 by hostname.

"Solution" is to force redeploy service_2. Once redeployed, `/etc/hosts` on service_2 will have new entry, pointing to `service1`.

My guess is that AWS Service Connect does not autorefresh `/etc/hosts` on already running services. Which in a way defeats the purpose of this service.

Since I only have one way dependency, I can utilise `depends_on` in Terraform, so that service_1 is up and running, before service_2 is deployed. But what if I had bi-directional dependency? Do I need to create both, then force-recreate one so that they can find each other?

*EDIT*

Relevant Terraform code snippets:

```
resource "aws_service_discovery_private_dns_namespace" "this" {
  name = "aws.internal"
  <...>
}

module "ecs_cluster" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/ecs/aws//modules/cluster"

  cluster_service_connect_defaults = {
    namespace = aws_service_discovery_private_dns_namespace.this.arn
  }
  <...>
}

module "service1" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/ecs/aws//modules/service"

  cluster_arn = module.ecs_cluster.arn

  <...>

  container_definitions = {
    <...>
    service1 = {
      <...>
      port_mappings = [
        {
          name          = "service1"
          containerPort = 8888
          hostPort      = 8888
          protocol      = "tcp"
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  service_connect_configuration = {
    enabled = true
    service = {
      client_alias = {
        port     = 8888
        dns_name = "service1"
      }
    port_name      = "service1"
    discovery_name = "service1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is an expected behaviour of ECS Service Connect.

> Existing services must be redeployed before the applications in them can resolve new endpoints.
> New endpoints that are added to the namespace after the most recent deployment won't be added to the task configuration.
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-connect.html

---

> I can utilise depends_on in Terraform, so that service_1 is up and running, before service_2 is deployed.

This is what AWS recommends as well as described in the [Service Connect Concept: Deployment Order](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-connect-concepts.html#service-connect-concepts-deploy)

> First, assume that you are creating an application that is available to the public internet in a single AWS CloudFormation template and single AWS CloudFormation stack.
>
> The public discovery and reachability should be created last by AWS CloudFormation, including the frontend client service. The services need to be created in this order to prevent an time period when the frontend client service is running and available the public, but a backend isn't. This eliminates error messages from being sent to the public during that time period.
>
> In AWS CloudFormation, you must use the dependsOn to indicate to AWS CloudFormation that multiple Amazon ECS services can't be made in parallel or simultaneously. You should add the dependsOn to the frontend client service for each backend client-server service that the client tasks connect to.

---

What you can try is to set both services as `Client and server` in Service Connect configuration and access them from each other using their DNS. E.g.: `service1.namespace` and `service2.namespace`.

> Client mode connects to other services in the namespace, and client-server mode provides endpoints for this service.

[image]

> If you don't provide a DNS name, the Port alias is used in the [Service Connect proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-connect-concepts.html#service-connect-concepts-proxy) configuration.

---

**Edit**

Your Namespace's `Instance discovery` should be set to `API calls and DNS queries in VPCs`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for confirming and references to the relevant documentation, this is very useful. As for your suggestion to set client-server - service1 is already client-server, but it doesn't seem to be able to resolve itself as service1.namespace, only as service1 (because that's what in hosts file).
I tried using aws_service_discovery_private_dns_namespace instead of aws_service_discovery_http_namespace, but that only makes zone DNS queryable (ie I can do 'dig namespace' and get SOA back), service1.namespace still returns not found, and services show discoverable by api calls only...

Comment: Did you redeploy your service after switching to `aws_service_discovery_private_dns_namespace`? Also check the Route53 hosted zone of your namespace if there's an entry for your service (and there should be).

Comment: I did, yes. With HTTP namespace that field was "API Calls only" and after switching to DNS Private namespace "Instance discovery: API calls and DNS queries". However, down at the bottom in the services list, the added service (service1) has "Discoverable by: API calls only" and I've no idea if it's possible to make this DNS discoverable, and if so, then how. In Route 53 zone, there's only two entries, zone SOA and NS records, there's no record for service1.

Comment: I've added terraform code that creates service and service connect configuration.

Comment: @rytis Did you find a solution for bi-directional dependency? Can it be handled?

Comment: @sebaszczen, unfortunately no, I don't think there's a way to force refresh without recreating resources. So if you have A needing B, and B needing A, then you'd have to create A, then B, at which point B knows about A, then recreate A, so that A knows about B...
I think best way is to use DNS based service discovery. It's going to take some time to update, but I think still better than rebuild. Example using both: https://github.com/rytis/iac-etudes/blob/8994faaa4fc4192e8bc5156be865fd7e06bc7d33/etudes/dask-cluster/aws/terraform/modules/dask_cluster/main.tf#L71-L85